# reactivemongo and reactivemongo-play-json dependency problems in sbt build

Tags: reactivemongo

When I include the following in my build.sbt (using Scala version 2.12.1)

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.12.1",
"org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo-play-json" % "0.12.1",
```

I get the error...

```
    Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'LowerImplicitBSONHandlers.class'.
    Could not access type Writes in package play.api.libs.json,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing.
    Check your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies
    (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
    A full rebuild may help if 'LowerImplicitBSONHandlers.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of play.api.libs.json.
```

Can reactivemongo and reactivemongo-play-json live together?

Thanks,
Nathaniel

Answer (score -1):

Seems you need to include play-json as a dependency if play isn't already included in your dependencies.  A bit strange, since I thought the whole idea of reactivemongo-play-json was to get the json support without requiring play.  Regardless, compilation now works after including the following dependency:
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0-M3"

Comment: That's indicated in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html): "If the dependency for the Play plugin (with the right version) is present, it already provides the JSON support and this JSON serialization pack must not be added as a separate dependency." BUT "If you want to use this JSON serialization outside of Play application, the dependency to the standalone Play JSON library must then be added: "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % version."